# Plot of confidence limits changes when I change the axis ticks and labels for a polynomial regression

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval, non-linear-regression, x-axis

A multiple regression with number of days from start of observations gives me a plot in which the confidence limits are shown for the entire range of x-values of the curve. When I change the ticks and labels on the plot to specific dates the CL do not extend to the first or last points. How can this be corrected?

**Full code that gives plot against days is this:**

```
frpd<-read_csv("frpd.csv")
ggplot(frpd, aes(x=Days, y=cover))+geom_point()
frpd.shuffled<-frpd[sample(nrow(frpd)),]
K<-10
degree<-5
folds<-cut(seq(1,nrow(frpd.shuffled)),breaks=K, labels=FALSE)
mse=matrix(data=NA,nrow=K,ncol=degree)
for(i in 1:K){
  testIndexes <- which(folds==i,arr.ind=TRUE)
  testData <- frpd.shuffled[testIndexes, ]
  trainData <- frpd.shuffled[-testIndexes, ]
  for (j in 1:degree){
    fit.train = lm(cover ~ poly(Days,j), data=trainData)
    fit.test = predict(fit.train, newdata=testData)
    mse[i,j] = mean((fit.test-testData$cover)^2) 
  }
}
colMeans(mse)
best = lm(cover ~ poly(Days,2, raw=T), data=frpd)
summary(best)
lm(formula=cover~poly(Days,2,raw=T),data=frpd)
ggplot(frpd, aes(x=Days, y=cover)) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method='lm', formula = y ~ poly(x,2), size = 1) + 
  xlab('Days') +
  ylab('cover')
```

**This produces the following plot:**
[Image from plot with Days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hi0Yy.jpg)

**To get a plot against dates I replaced the geom-plot code with this:**

```
geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(15, 74, 135, 196, 257, 318),
                     labels = c("1 Feb", "1 Apr", "1 Jun", "1 Aug", "1 Oct", "1 Dec",)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), breaks = seq(0, 100, 20)) +
  ylab('cover') +
  xlab('date')
```

This is the resulting plot:
[Image of plot against dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oubq7.jpg)

**I tried** adding breaks at c(1) and c(362) and matching labels "" and "".
It did not extend the range of CL's.

Comment: Using `limits = c(0, 100)` in `scale_y_continuous` you drop the part of the CI ribbon which falls outside of the limits, i.e. which extend to > 100. Instead use `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 100))` to zoom or focus on a range of the scale.

Comment: So I use the following plot code:

Comment: ggplot(frpd, aes(x=Days, y=cover)) + 
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(15, 74, 135, 196, 257, 318),
                     labels = c("1 Feb", "1 Apr", "1 Jun", "1 Aug", "1 Oct", "1 Dec")) +
  scale_y_continuous(coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100)), breaks = seq(0, 100, 20)) +
  ylab('cover') +
  xlab('date')

This produced the following error which I cannot interpret in relation to the code displayed:

Error in as.vector(x, "character") : 
  cannot coerce type 'environment' to vector of type 'character'

Comment: Nop. `... + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 100, 20)) + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100))`. The `coord` is a different and separate type of layer.

Comment: Changed the coding as suggested but the plot does not change.
ggplot(frpd, aes(x = Days, y = cover)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ poly(x, 2), size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(15, 74, 135, 196, 257, 318),
                     labels = c("1 Feb", "1 Apr", "1 Jun", "1 Aug", "1 Oct", "1 Dec")) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), breaks = seq(0, 100, 20)) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100))+
  ylab('cover') +
  xlab('date')

Comment: As shown in my comment. Drop `limits = c(0, 100)` from scale_y_continuous.

Comment: Great! I misinterpreted your comment. All good now!